# Break list and list item Inheritance REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, break-inheritance

I tried this :

[image]

But get error: **"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."**

Knowing that accessing the list 'Clients' **works**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when you create an AppId and AppSecret for SharePoint, There is a step when you use **Permission Request XML** in order to give permission the your app, you should give it **"FullControl"** right to let you do what ever action you want.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

I hope this will fix your error,

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You likely have "Contribute" access to the list, which will allow you to view, add, edit and delete items *in* the list, but not make any changes to *the list itself*.

What you need is "Edit" permission, because that adds the ability to manage lists, which will allow you to change the permissions set on the list itself.

[Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels#list-permissions-and-permission-levels) are two Microsoft articles explaining permission levels in SharePoint.